# SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition TDE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transparent-data-encryption

I have `Standard Edition` of `SQL Server 2016`.
Is it possible to enable TDE?

I understand that it was an enterprise feature but it is now a feature for `SQL 2019 Standard` and therefore I wondered if there was a way to add this feature for `SQL 2016 Standard` now?

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You can see the [full feature list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15).

There were several things opened up for 2016 in Standard with the release of SP1. TDE was not one of them.

Comment: OK thanks. I have now purchased Standard Edition of SQL Server 2019 so that we can take advantage of TDE :)

Comment: Best of luck. BTW, check this out in 2019. It's one of the single greatest reasons to upgrade: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts?view=sql-server-ver15